# Switch existing organizations to use the new domain name URL

Tags: azure-devops

If [we switch our organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/sep-10-azure-devops-launch#administration) to the new dev.azure.com/myorg URL, would the old myorg.visualstudio.com URL still work?

Answer (score 3):

Yes - I just verified with mine. I've been using the dev.azure.com/myorg format and the old myorg.visualstudio.com still works for me.